# Specify the AccessibilityService capability

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

On the Android Api guide for the [fingerprint accessibility service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html), the following sentence is written :

> 1. Declare the USE_FINGERPRINT permission and the CAPABILITY_CAN_REQUEST_FINGERPRINT_GESTURES capability.

However, I can't seem to find where to actually declare the capability. Is it in the AccessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes field ? Is it declared programatically or in the xml accessibilityService file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
USE_FINGERPRINT
```

Is just a manifest permission and declared like any other permission. CAPABILITY_CAN_REQUEST_FINGERPRINT_GESTURES is an accessibility service capability, and is declared in your service config xml file as such:

```
<accessibility-service 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:accessibilityFlags="otherFlags|flagRequestFingerprintGestures"
    android:canRequestFingerprintGestures="true"
    ... 
    />
```

Best reference page to discover all of this stuff:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html#CAPABILITY_CAN_REQUEST_FINGERPRINT_GESTURES